# Why did my terminal suddenly has darwin13 as host? How do I fix this?

Tags: terminal

I was trying to install Kaggle but then all of a u sudden I see:
@x86_64-apple-darwin13  on my terminal.

How do I switch this back? I was trying some solutions I found online but every time I run  open  ~.bash_profile  it says:
**zsh: no such user or named directory: .bash_profile**

Comment: Has your machine's hostname really changed? What happens if you run `hostname` from the terminal?

Comment: I didn't do anything, other than trying to install a Kaggle via pip. When I run hostname it showed "archos"

Comment: See: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7031, and you need to modify ~/.zshrc, not .bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

Every time turn on terminal, conda will be activated automatically.
Try the following command should work

conda config --set auto_activate_base false

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my issue. I had a `darwin 13` at the end of my host name and after running the above command, closing and opening the terminal, it went away!